# Calculating age derived from current date and DOB in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, debugging, laravel-query-builder

I have a laravel project where I am counting age from DOB and current date.

```
$query_count->where('dob', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($data));
```

I can calculate count dob if not inside query like

```
Carbon::parse('1988-11-15')->age
```

How to do it inside a query like this?

```
->where('SELECT timediff()...
```

Answer (score 0):

With datediff you get the days between two dates:

```
Select datediff(DateA, DateB) from Table;
```

Comment: this is the query
````$query_count->where('dob', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($data)````

where to add 'select datediff(...) ?